# Relations between hypergeometric functions

Tags: partial-derivative, hypergeometric-function, wolfram-alpha

I am trying to find a relation between hypergeometrics $${}_2F_1(a,b,c;z)\,\,\text{and}\,\,{}_2F_1(a+1,b+1,c+1;z)$$

I can see that $$\frac{\partial}{\partial z}{}_2F_1(a,b,c;z) = \frac{ab}{c}{}_2F_1(a+1,b+1,c+1;z)$$ but I was wondering if I can write a relation between them that admits the form $${}_2F_1(a+1,b+1,c+1;z) = f(a,b,c,z) \cdot {}_2F_1(a,b,c;z) + \,\,\text{some other hypergeometric} $$

I know there is a hypergeometric identities page on Wolfram with a plethora of identities, but I couldn't see such an identity for the case I am considering. I am not sure, however, if this list is exhaustive.

Thanks!

Comment: What parameters you would like "some other hypergeometric" to have?

Comment: @Startwearingpurple: I was hoping the 'some other hypergeometric' would actually be a trivial hypergeometric in the sense that its arguments are such that the hypergeometric turns out to be just $z$ to some power or something at least simpler than a hypergeometric.

Comment: Did you look at: http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.5.E19 ?  Which is basically the discrete extension of the differential equation.

Comment: In addition if a,b,c are integer you can almost certainly transform the series into a combinatorial summation.

Answer (score 1):

Little late to the game here but your request is possible by using the [contigious relations](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1110256X1200020X) of the hypergeometric function. Using the notation in the linked paper
$$
F\left({a_1+1,a_2+1\atop a_3+1};x\right)=\mathcal A_1\mathcal A_2\mathcal A_3 F\left({a_1,a_2\atop a_3};x\right).
$$
There are a number of operators you can derive from the contigious relations that will be equivalent to $\mathcal A_1\mathcal A_2\mathcal A_3$. For example, equation $(17)$ gives $\mathcal A_1\mathcal A_2\mathcal A_3=-\frac{a_3}{a_2 z}(\mathcal I-\mathcal A_1)$ so that
$$
\begin{aligned}
F\left({a_1+1,a_2+1\atop a_3+1};x\right)%
&=-\frac{a_3}{a_2 z}(\mathcal I-\mathcal A_1) F\left({a_1,a_2\atop a_3};x\right)\\
&=-\frac{a_3}{a_2 z}F\left({a_1,a_2\atop a_3};x\right)+\frac{a_3}{a_2 z}F\left({a_1+1,a_2\atop a_3};x\right),
\end{aligned}
$$
which is in the form presented in the question.

If any of the parameters $a_1$, $a_2$, or $a_3$ are integers it is likely that repeated application of these contigious relations can reduce the second hypergeometric term above to some "simpler" product of elementary functions.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have the answer for the general form you asked.  However, I found out one special case which was useful for my work: a = b = c -1.  Here is the relation:

$_2F_1(K+1, K+1; K+2; x) = \frac{K+1}{Kx}\big[\frac{1}{(1-x)^K}-_2F_1(K,K;K+1;x)\big]$

Proof can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1016616/hypergeometric-function-integral-representation).