# Closed form for $\int \sqrt[n]{\tan x}\ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, power-series, indefinite-integrals, closed-form

I was solving $\displaystyle\int\sqrt[n]{\tan x}\ dx$.

**Here's my method:**

$$\begin{align}\int\sqrt[n]{\tan x}\ dx &= \int\frac{n \cdot t^n}{1 + (t)^{2n}}\tag{1}\ dt\\& = n \int\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k (t)^{2nk}\cdot t^n \ dt\tag{2} \\& = n\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k \int t^{2nk+n}\ dt \tag{3}\\& = n \sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k \frac{t^{2nk +n+1}}{2nk +n+1} + C\tag{4}\\& =n \sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k \frac{(\tan x)^{\frac{2nk +n+1}n}}{2nk +n+1} + C\tag{5} \\& = \boxed{n \sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k \frac{(\tan x)^{2k +\frac{n+1}n}}{2nk +n+1} + C}\end{align}$$

---

**Steps:**

> - $(1)$ Substitution: $\tan{x} = t^n$
> - $(2)$ Taylor series: $\displaystyle\frac{1}{1+t} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k (t)^k\implies \frac{1}{1+t^{2n}} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k (t^{2n})^k$.
> - $(3)$ Interchanged integral and summation symbols.
> - $(4)$ Used power rule of integration.
> - $(5)$ Undone the substitution.

---

**Source:**

I was practicing integral calculus and came across $\displaystyle \int \sqrt{\tan x}\ dx$ and $\displaystyle \int \sqrt[3]{\tan x}\ dx $. Both of them were nice and I solved them. So I thought there would be definitely a general solution for $\displaystyle \int \sqrt[n]{\tan x}\ dx$ where $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

---

**My question:**

Answers for $\int \sqrt{\tan x}\ dx$ and $\sqrt[3]{\tan {x}} $ were looking good, at least elementary (Having closed form). I expected the same for $\int \sqrt[n]{\tan x}\ dx$. Is there any closed form for $n \sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k \frac{(\tan x)^{2k +\frac{n+1}n}}{2nk +n+1} + C$? And is my method right?

Comment: First step should be $\tan x=t^n$, right?

Comment: The closed form is [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ddx+%28n+2F1%281%2C+1%2F2+%2B+1%2F%282+n%29%2C+3%2F2+%2B+1%2F%282+n%29%2C+-%28sin%5E2%28x%29%29%2F%28cos%5E2%28x%29%29%29+%28sin%28x%29%2Fcos%28x%29%29%5E%281+%2B+1%2Fn%29%29%2F%281+%2B+n%29) and using a [transformation](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/06/05/0025/) it is a Lerch transcendent or [incomplete beta $\text B_z(a,0)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=beta%28x%2Ca%2C0%29) expression. For rational $n$, there should be a closed form with a finite sum of logarithms.

Comment: @AndrésMartínez Yes. A typo. I'll fix it.

Comment: @TymaGaidash Thanks. I think beta function and Hypergeometric function are beyond the limits of my knowledge.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1998618/factorize-x2n1-to-evaluate-int-tan1-nxdx, which this question arguably duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply the partial decomposition
\begin{align}
\frac{nt^n}{1+t^{2n}}= \sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k+1}
 \frac{t\sin \theta_k}{1-2t\cos \theta_k + t^2}, \>\>\>\>\>\theta_k=\frac{(2k-1)\pi}{2n}
\end{align}
and, with $t= \sqrt[n]{\tan x}$, integrate to obtain the close form below
\begin{align}
& \int\sqrt[n]{\tan x}\> dx= \int \frac{nt^n}{1+t^{2n}}dt\\
=& \sum_{k=0}^{n}{(-1)^{k+1}}\left[ {\sin \theta_k}
\ln\sqrt{1- 2t\cos \theta_k + t^2}
+\cos \theta_k
\tan^{-1}\frac{t- \cos \theta_k}{\sin \theta_k}
\right]
\end{align}